# angular selectable mat-optgroup

Tags: angular, angular-material

I would like to have a mat-select multiple with selectable optgroup like this example

[image: selectable mat-select optgroup]

I can't find any documentation on this, is there a way to achieve it with material built-in tools ?

Comment: Have you tried it? If you did then you already know whether or not it works. Please tell us.

Comment: I get a code working as I expect, by adding a mat-checkbox before my mat-optgroup.
I was just wondering if there is built in material way to do it

Comment: You should revise your question to ask that question, not ask what you already know.